# Proper error handling in Kotlin with Coroutines

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a dilemma about handling exceptions in kotlin and coroutines. Will be thankful for any articles or your personal experience.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/exceptions.html#checked-exceptions kotlin documentation says that exceptions were mistake so there are no checked exceptions in kotlin.

If you have multilayer architecture it is pain in the ass to handle an exception from bottom layer at the top one, cause there are no warnings or compile level checks for what exception you should wait for.

As an option you can catch exception asap, wrap it with some `Result` class and propagate it back as a return value.

```
return try {
   Result.Success(api.call())
} catch(ex: IOException) {
   Result.NetworkError
}
```

This solution works well until you get hands on coroutines with async/await.

If an exception is thrown inside the first async then whole scope becomes dead.

```
coroutineScope {
    val r1 = async { }
    val r2 = async { } 
    r1.await()
    r2.await()
}
```

But if you use solution with return value, then both async will complete. Even if one of them completed with wrapped error. In 99% cases this behavior doesn't make sense.

So I run into situation interesting situation - there are no compile level/lint checks for catching/throwing checked exceptions so I can't use exceptions properly. But if I get rid of exceptions coroutines start act weird.

Comment: If you want one coroutine to continue to completion even if the other fails, don't put them in the same `coroutineScope` block. That function is specifically for running a set of coroutines that must either all succeed or be cancelled if any fail.

Comment: @Tenfour04 "That function is specifically for running a set of coroutines that must either all succeed or be cancelled if any fail" yes and this behavior can be reached only with exceptions. You can not reach it by default if you wrap you exceptions into `Result`

Comment: This is what my question about. How to provide exceptions from bottom to top properly, if usage of exceptions is not 'stable' (no compile checks, etc, it is easy to make a mistake)

Comment: Wrap `coroutineScope` in `runCatching` and allow the inner coroutines to throw and fail. Side note, if you want prompter cancellation of the sibling coroutines, put all the returned Deferreds in a list and call `awaitAll()`. Otherwise, if you call `await()` on a coroutine that takes longer than the others before calling `await()` on them, it will run to completion even if its siblings are failing.

Comment: If you have already wrapped into a Result at a lower level, you can `getOrThrow()` on it before returning from your inner coroutine.

Comment: @Tenfour04 "If you have already wrapped into a Result at a lower level, you can getOrThrow() on it before returning from your inner coroutine." great idea, thx

Comment: Honestly, I don't really see your point on wrapping exceptions into `Result` in such scenario. How is it better than unchecked exceptions? Exceptions in `Result` are untyped, so returning `Result` only says: "I may fail, handle it.". But well, every method may always fail, so I don't see added value here.

Comment: @broot I wrap it in a custom result, where error state wrapps not exception, but enum or sealed class

Comment: Ahh, ok, I thought you mean `Result` from Kotlin stdlib. Nevermind :-)